# jQuery hover scrolling, just need a little assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, scroller

Im not really a jQuery buff. So i come here looking for some help.

Here is the idea. There are ten images, and ten thumbnails. When you mouse over the thumbnail it will take you to the corresponding image (My code is on  jsbin http://jsbin.com/ayigew/1/edit).

What i would like to have is this over feature to be added to the green bars on the top and bottom.

The idea is that i could mouse over the top bar and it will scroll up to the next picture in the list.
If i hover over the bottom green bar it will take me to the next image in the list.

Here is what i have so far http://jsbin.com/ayigew/1/edit

So instead of having to mouse over the thumbnail, you mouse over the green bar at the top or bottom to go forward and backward.

I hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean something like [this](http://jsbin.com/ayigew/8/edit)? I did it using timers. On enter start timer. go up or down every x ms and clear the timer on mouse leave.

Comment: That works very well!! Thanks for helping me figure it out. I also looked at using jquery hoverscroll but it is way more complicated.